# Is there a bug in ASP.NET's User-Agent interpretation for custom builds of Firefox?

Tags: asp.net, firefox, user-agent

For the user agent string

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)
```

`HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.MajorVersion` returns `3` and `HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.MinorVersion` returns `5`. So far so good.

However for this user agent string (seen in the wild by one of my users)

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 (CK-Finbu.com) Firefox/3.6 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)
```

`HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.MajorVersion` returns `1` and `HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.MinorVersion` returns `9`. It looks like ASP.NET has picked up the numbers from the CVS tag info rather than the browser version.

Does this mean that ASP.NET's user agent parsing is broken?

Comment: I wanted to tag this is-select-broken, but I couldn't as I don't have enough rep :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you'll need to tweak your `mozilla.browser` file (in `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\Browsers\` folder).

Around line 188, you'll see this (regex to match Firefox browser):

```
"Gecko\/\d+ Firefox\/(?'version'(?'major'\d+)(?'minor'\.[.\d]*))"
```

Should be

```
"Gecko\/\d+(?: \S+)? Firefox\/(?'version'(?'major'\d+)(?'minor'\.[.\d]*))"
```

Comment: So SELECT is broken. My colleague has this user agent string, which looks like the standard one for Firefox on Ubuntu. It won't match that regex either.

Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-GB; rv:1.9.1.7) Gecko/20100106 Ubuntu/9.10 (karmic) Firefox/3.5.7

Comment: Mozilla have a document about that: https://developer.mozilla.org/User_Agent_Strings_Reference ; according this document, that UA is wrong